# MySql + PHP Group by, Having and Order By used together returns - no results

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do a query to get closest (by km -> radius) users for given coordinates.
Everything works, but because I'm saving last 10 locations want to take the very last location per user in single query.

```
   SELECT `id`, `user_id`, (6371 * acos( cos( radians(42.698201) ) * cos( radians(map_lat) ) * 
 cos( radians(map_lon) - radians(23.318825)) + sin(radians(42.698201)) *
 sin(radians(map_lat)) )) as distance, `map_lat`, `map_lon`, `date_added`
FROM (`map_locations`)
WHERE `user_id` !=  '3'
HAVING `distance` < 1000
ORDER BY `date_added` desc
```

This returns me each row with the desired distance correctly.

Now I want to `GROUP BY` `user_id` and for an example if there are 2 unique users -> to get their last locations Ordered by `date_added`

Example of result that I want:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 22
            [user_id] => 1
            [distance] => 1.4498781932309621
            [map_lat] => 42.7028
            [map_lon] => 23.3022
            [date_added] => 2017-09-07 14:45:21
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 21
            [user_id] => 2
            [distance] => 912.4120338405637
            [map_lat] => 43.4124
            [map_lon] => 12.1231
            [date_added] => 2017-09-07 14:24:59
        )
```

Unfortunately when I add `Group By` statement gives me 0 results, because is getting the first result for each user (Ordering doesn't work for sure).

My research is that if `Group By` works properly with grouping results by `date_added` Having would work correctly after it

With other words: Want to take all unique users with their last locations if the last location of each user matches the distance criteria.

Comment: `Group by` would work but I think it's not working due to the time stamp. It's not consistent seconds minutes they change. Did you try grouping them with out the time stamp.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this...

```
SELECT distinct `user_id`, `id`,
(6371 * acos( cos( radians(42.698201) ) * cos( radians(map_lat) ) * 
cos( radians(map_lon) - radians(23.318825)) + sin(radians(42.698201)) *
sin(radians(map_lat)) )) as distance, `map_lat`, `map_lon`, `date_added`
FROM (`map_locations`)
WHERE `user_id` !=  '3'
GROUP BY `user_id`
HAVING `distance` < 1000
ORDER BY `date_added` desc
```

Answer (score -2):

I just made the same query in Oracle DB so you can adapt it on MySQL without difficulty.

I used **a different trigonometric function** because my lat/lon data are stored as **"radians" coordinates** in my table.

***So you must check your data format and accuracy*** before doing anything.

For example, to find how many elements are present in a range of 50 km from the origin point [38.1862, 15.5564] (in *decimal*) = [0.6664, 0.2715] (in *radians*) :

```
select count(*) 
from my_table
where acos(sin(0.6664) * sin(latitude) + cos(0.6664) * cos(latitude) * cos(longitude - (0.2715))) * 6371 < 50
```

Comment: That absolutely does not answer the question.